# wifi card not recognizable at ubuntu 14.04 3.19.0-61-lowlatency

Tags: 14.04, networking, kernel

I installed a new partition in my PC with ubuntu 14.04 with lowlatency kernel:
uname -a:
3.19.0-61-lowlatency #69~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 9 10:15:00 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The wifi card works and is recognizable at the other partition and even in the normal kernel, but with lowlatency kernel:

rfkill list:
0:hcio: Bluetooth
        soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
without giving the wifi informations.

Ps: I can't connect my computer to Internet via Ethernet.

And the wlan0 config gives:
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found.

I tryied to add the wlan0 interface on the interfaces files:
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
And still does'nt working.

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a) 
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:0010] 
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265] [1002:6604] (rev ff) 
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Please help me.
Best regards.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I added the command result on my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have an obsolete kernel that does not support this wireless adapter. You can upgrade your kernel to 4.4 and get the support.

Connect to the internet by wire or some other way and run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency-lts-xenial
```

and reboot. This will upgrade your lowlatency kernel.

You may also need to install firmware for this adapter if it does not work. Post the output of `dmesg | grep iwl` if this is the case.

Comment: Thank you for answering my quetion,                                                                         but the problem is that i am working on an application that require to install this kernel version.                                                                                                                                  is an other soltion

Comment: The 3.19 kernel does not support Intel 8260 wireless adapter. And what is the application that requires a specific kernel? If you need a lowlatency, the 4.4 will be a lowlatency as well. The 3.19 kernel is not supported any more.

Comment: It's an application that need the real time kernel to run a network software code.

Comment: So you will have a newer "real time kernel".

Comment: Ok thank you a lot, My problem is that i don't have a adapted ethernet wire for my laptop to connect to internet and install the new kernel version. but because it's a unique solution, i will try to get it.                                   thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

solved:

sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/12/18/backports-20151218.tar.gz

tar -zvxf backports-20151218.tar.gz

cd backports-20151218

make defconfig-iwlwifi

make

sudo make install